# VSCode practically unusable with slow intellisense without using extensions

Tags: typescript, ide, visual-studio-code

VSCode on my Macbook Pro is practically unusable due to the intellisense being ungodly slow. This includes:

- hovering to find typescript types, inferred and explicit types
- autocomplete variables/functions/etc
- autocomplete for using shortcuts
- error lines shown in editor

For example, I will have an error show. Something like "variable not defined" or something simple. But then when I go to rewrite the code, it takes forever for VSCode to catch up. Sometimes I have to let it sit 40-50seconds before it catches up with my changes.
Hovering over typescript types is practically impossible at times and utterly useless. Below is a screenshot of the "lag" - changes were made, but it stuck like this for 30+ seconds:

[image]

- It may be the specific project, because I can't recreate it for smaller projects. However, its only a 200k line project.
- No specific extensions are slowing down VScode
- I tried downgrading VsCode with no help

VSCODE VERSION: 1.47.3

Comment: As a remedy, you may want to try installing `ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next` for [Partial Editing Mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#partial-editing-mode-at-startup) - Although this also upgrades vscodes typescript to 4.0

Comment: already installed @EliasSchablowski

Comment: The only other thing to try would be to remove the typescript cache, or checking on a different computer (maybe the FS isn't fast enough)

Comment: @EliasSchablowski so if its slow on another machine its the project? could that mean too many types? wrong configuration in eslint?

Comment: It could be a lot of different things, among them are that it could just be too large/complex to be performant - Although you may try disabling the eslint plugin to check for invalid configs on that side (I've personally had this issue before - not invalid just eslint sometimes slows vscode down)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was GitLens. I was able to isolate this issue by using the Command Palette (Control + Shift + P) to disable all extensions (this will not uninstall them), restarted Visual Studio, then checked if the issue persists.

The issue did indeed persist, so I went into the Extensions tab [image: extensions tab] and filtered by `@disabled:`

[image: disabled filter]

By reenabling my extensions one by one, I found GitLens to be the culprit.

Comment: I experienced this too - it appeared to me that the GitLens extension was committing my changes on every keystroke, probably so it could have unlimited undo.