# How do I speed up Typescript Intelisense in VsCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

this is my computer:

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
- 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
- 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

When working with typescript in angular this happens:
[image]

The bigger the project the longer I have to wait for this to load. Really ruins my developer experience. Is there a way I can assign more resources to vs code so it runs faster? Are there any optimizations that I can do to make it work?

Solutions attempted:

- [Extremely Slow Typescript VSCode Intellisense](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82846)
- [Extremely slow intellisense menu? No extensions loaded whatsoever.](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/bfie6n/extremely_slow_intellisense_menu_no_extensions/)
- [Extensive CPU usage / Slow TypeScript Intellisense](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83474)
- [VS Code Intellisense is extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60634012/vs-code-intellisense-is-extremely-slow) (there is no .vs file see screenshot below)
- [Visual Studio Code Intellisense is very slow - Is there anything I can do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874486/visual-studio-code-intellisense-is-very-slow-is-there-anything-i-can-do)
- [VSCode practically unusable with slow intellisense without using extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363846/vscode-practically-unusable-with-slow-intellisense-without-using-extensions)

Example Project structure:

- [image: project structure]

Comment: I had a similar problem. I downloaded Vscode Insiders where the problem is fixed.

Comment: My vscode freeze on initiate angular language service too, or initiate css

Answer (score 31):

Disabling this made it lightning quick.

**Try this to see if it is a particular extension.**

- Open Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
- Type in "Disable all installed extensions"
- Enable them one by one or in groups and test the
  IntelliSense speed

Comment: GitLens was the culprit for me.

Comment: You can do the same with the command `Extension Bisect`. VS Code will guide you through finding the troubled extension

Comment: @kendepelchin extension bisect is super cool! I identified `IntelliCode API Usage Examples` extension to be using a similar slowness issue for me. Thanks Microsoft for pushing this one onto me for testing :D

Comment: Bisect is awesome! It should be the correct answer for this question

Answer (score 11):

Options :

- Disable the built-in extensions and restart the computer
- Disable eslint and tslint-plugin
- Depends on your VsCode version

Comment: This worked thank you! ESLint and Gitlens being disabled fixed the slowness. The intelisense AND the errors now show instantly

Answer (score 6):

Just go to settings, search for and check this box >

```
TypeScript: Disable Automatic Type Acquisition
```

[image]

Comment: This is a useful feature, I'm not sure OP want to disable it

Comment: Wow, this feature was causing all sorts of inconsistencies for me, didn't even know it existed. @types are cool and all but sometimes they're wrong/outdated and I've removed them from my package.json but apparently this thing has been downloading and using them anyway, but only sometimes, for some reason.

Comment: I thought this feature is only relevant to JavaScript files. I've never seen @types packages fetched automatically in TypeScript files, I've had to install them explicitly into my project. Intellisense in my TS files is still slow with disabled automatic type acquisition.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mongoose, some versions also cause this (5x and apparently some of the 6x). Updating mongoose or switching for prisma might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I myself faced this issue. To fix this I changed the typescript SDK that VScode uses.
First get the latest version of Typescript globally using npm or yarn.

```
npm i -g typescript@latest
```

Then, you'll need to get the location where your typescript library is installed globally, to do so run the following command

```
npm root -g
```

This will give the path of global `node_modules`.
For eg, `C:\Users\bob\npm\node_modules`
Then in VSCode settings search for typescript.tsdk and in the input field paste the path that you copied from the last command and append `/typescript/lib`.
For eg, `C:\Users\bob\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib`
[image]

Then try restarting VSCode...
Hope this thread helps :)

Answer (score 0):

go to extensions and type typescript look for important extensions that say `Reload Required` if you see any; do it.

for me `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` required a reload.